# How to save battery life in Dell Vostro 3446 (Ubuntu 15.04)

Tags: dell, power-management, battery

I have both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 15.04 on my Vostro 3446. I noticed that when I'm on Windows 7 I get easily 4-5 hours of battery life but when I'm on Ubuntu, it barely lasts 1.5-2 hours. I cam across few articles to switch Bluetooth off and lower the brightness levels, but that didn't help.

P.S.: If a solution is an app/terminal code related, request you all to please provide a step by step guide as I'm new to Ubuntu. I love the OS but just don't want to give up on it because of a battery issue. I'm sure there's a solution out there.

Hardware Specs:

Intel i3 4th Gen
500GB 
nVidia GEFORCE 820m 2GB Dedicated Graphics Card

Installed Apps:
Clementine Music Player
VLC Player

Thanks in Advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

The laptop consumes a lot of power because both video adapters always work.
You need to install Nvidia proprietary video drivers and switch to integrated video.
Nvidia graphics acceleration is needed mostly for gaming.

Run in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

And reboot.

After that you will be able to switch video adapters in NVIDIA X Server Settings application.

If after reboot graphics do not start (this happen sometimes), then press Ctrl+Alt+F1, login to console and run

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

And reboot again.

I hope this will not be necessary. Otherwise we will install a newer driver.

Comment: I did as you asked. NVIDIA X Server Settings was installed, I rebooted, switched from NVIDIA (Performance Mode) to Intel (Power Saving Mode), it asked me to log out and log in again to apply the changes and I did. Tested it rest of the day; however, there wasn't any significant change. 
Did I miss something? I just did as you asked.. Is there any other solution or work around? I don't wanna stay around the charger every now and then.

Thank you I appreciate your help. :)